# Indexing files and parsing name

Tags: bash, shell, filenames

I have a directory, `./grd_files/lat36/` that has 7 files in it (`n36e114.grd`, `n36e115.grd`, `n36e116.grd`, `n36e117.grd`, `n36e118.grd`, `n36e119.grd`, `n36e120.grd`. Also beneath `./grd_files/` are other folders named `lat37`, `lat38`, `lat39`. Each contains some files named in the same format as those in `lat36`, only instead of `n36e114.grd`, the file for the `e114` longitude in the `lat37` folder would be called `n37e114`. Now, not all lat** folders contain all the longitudes, but I need them to.

I have written a part of the script to determine which lat** folder has the most columns in it (it is `lat36` with 7 longitudes). I want to compare the longitudes that exist in `lat36` folder to the other folders, and if a column is missing in another folder, I will make it. I can handle the `if then` statement, but I am stumped on how to compare the lists in bash.

*I was thinking to make a list of the file names in the `row1` folder, and compare that to the to the files in the other folders, but the names won't and shouldn't match -- only the column part of the name will and should match. So far I have tried to make an array of the file names and then parse it for just the column part of the name. Note that these are actually map tiles, so the names are really in the format of coordinates in northing (row) and easing (col) e.g. `n36e114.grd`. So I want to isolate all the `e114` style parts of the names and check and make sure that they exist in the other rows. I hope that makes sense. Below is what I attempted, but I am not great in bash syntax so I'm stumped. Thanks so much for the help. 
    col_list_raw=( $(find $maxdirectory -name "*.grd" -exec basename {} .grd \;) )
    col_list=( for c in ${col_list_raw[@]}; do echo ${col_list_raw[$c]:3:7}; done )
where `$maxdirectory` is the one with the most columns.*

---

UPDATE: I have removed what I described in italics above and attempted to incorporate the solution from John1024. Below is the code.

```
cd ./grd_files  
for row in lat*/
    do
        ls "$row"  | sed 's/.*lon/lon/' >"${row%/}.tmp"
done
for f in lat*.tmp
    do
        grep -vFf "$f" ${latXX}.tmp >missing.tmp
        [ -s missing.tmp ] && echo ${f%.tmp} is missing $(cat missing.tmp)
done
cd ..
```

Where `latXX` is the folder with the most longitudes. John1024's first loop works nicely, and I get the correct lists for each of the `lat**` folders, but the second loop straight up compares the lists , returning:

```
lat37 is missing n36e114.grd n36e115.grd n36e116.grd n36e117.grd n36e118.grd n36e119.grd n36e120.grd
lat38 is missing n36e114.grd n36e115.grd n36e116.grd n36e117.grd n36e118.grd n36e119.grd n36e120.grd
lat39 is missing n36e114.grd n36e115.grd n36e116.grd n36e117.grd n36e118.grd n36e119.grd n36e120.grd
```

I need that loop to compare only *part* of the file name. ie I want to check each folder for the existence of each longitude. So that if file `n37e114.grd' exists, nothing happens, but if it does not exist, that information is returned and I can execute a command based on the missing file. I hope my edits clear up the naming convention and are understandable. Thanks again for the help. AM

---

SOLUTION:

thanks to the help of @John1024 I was able to find a solution. I have reproduced the final solution below. Following this, I read in the *.out files and conduct my command on each line of them.

```
cd ./grd_files  
for lat in */
    do
    ls "$lat" | sed 's/[a-z][1-9][1-9].*\([a-z][0-9][0-9]*\).grd/\1/' >"${lat%/}.tmp"
done
for file in *.tmp
    do
    lat=$(echo $file | awk -F "." '{print $1}')
    grep -vFf "$file" ${xXX}.tmp >${lat}missing.out
    [ -s ${lat}missing.out ] && echo ${file%.tmp} is missing $(cat ${lat}missing.out)
done
```

Comment: The data example together with the wanted output worth 1000 words...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question includes two different naming schemes for the files.  Both would work the same, but to keep it simple and intuitive, this answer uses the first scheme.

It is possible to loop through bash arrays to find the missing columns.  However, `grep` is well-suited to this task, greatly simplifies the logic, and, if there are many columns and rows, it is likely much faster.  Using `grep`:

```
cd ./grd_files
for row in row*/
do
    ls "$row"  | sed 's/.*col/col/' >"${row%/}.tmp"
done
for f in row*.tmp
do
    grep -vFf "$f" row1.tmp >missing.tmp
    [ -s missing.tmp ] && echo ${f%.tmp} is missing $(cat missing.tmp)
done
```

The first loop above, creates lists of columns that exist in each of the rows.  These lists are saved in temporary files name row1.tmp, row2.tmp, etc.

The second loop compares each of those lists to the reference row, row1.tmp.  The list of columns missing from that row are saved in temporary file missing.tmp.  If missing.tmp has a nonzero size, then there are missing columns and a report is generated.

For cleanup, one might want to delete the tmp files.  If so, add this line to the end of the script:

```
rm row*.tmp missing.tmp
```

#### Fancier version

Using process substitution, the need for many of the temporary files can be eliminated:

```
trap "rm missing.tmp" EXIT
for row in row*/
do
    ls row1/  | sed 's/.*col/col/' | grep -vFf <(ls "$row"  | sed 's/.*col/col/') >missing.tmp
    [ -s missing.tmp ] && echo $row is missing $(cat missing.tmp)
done
```

This version also uses `trap` to assure that the sole remaining temporary file is removed when the script is finished.

#### Using the other naming scheme as per revised question

```
cd ./grd_files  
for row in lat*/
    do
        ls "$row"  | sed 's/.*n[0-9][0-9]e/e/' >"${row%/}.tmp"
done
for f in lat*.tmp
    do
        grep -vFf "$f" ${latXX}.tmp >missing.tmp
        [ -s missing.tmp ] && echo ${f%.tmp} is missing $(cat missing.tmp)
done
cd ..
```

Comment: @amoodie I see.  With the new naming scheme, the `sed` command is not doing its job: it should remove everything up to the longitude spec.  See updated answer and then check that latitude is removed from your tmp files.

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in the comment, supplying the test data is a good practice. In this case you would got much more answers if supplied a script what creating a test case, something such next:

```
mkdir grid
cd grid
mkdir lat3{5..9}
    #if you don't know the {3..9} expansion, simply write
    #mkdir lat36 lat37 lat38 lat39
touch lat35/n35e111.grd
touch lat36/n36e11{4..9}.grd lat36/n36e120.grd
touch lat37/n37e11{4,6,8}.grd
touch lat38/n38e11{4..9}.grd
#39 missing all files
```

Such script what creating an test case helps much more as full page of words. ;) Or, if no script, at least supply the output of `find` like `find grid -print`. Your first edit helps a bit, (I missed it) and +100 to @John1024's work.

Now about the solution.

Your final solution have one problem. What if the directory with the *MOST LONGITUDES* (your latXX) missing some gridfile what exists in some other directories? E.g. it has the most gridfiles, but still not *all*. Like in the above test case, the `lat36` contains 7 files (most of all), but sill missing a file `n36e111.grd` (because the 111 exists *only* in the lat35)?

Therefore i created an alternative solution, what eliminates this problem and show the result as the next matrix:

```
    111 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
35: +   no  no  no  no  no  no  no      # the 111 is here
36: no  +   +   +   +   +   +   +       # the dir with a MOST of longitudes but missing 111
37: no  +   no  +   no  +   no  no
38: no  +   +   +   +   +   +   no
39: no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no      # missing all longitudes
```

the script

```
start="./test/grid"
cd "$start" || err "can cd to $start" || exit 1

known_longs=$(find . -type f -name \*.grd -print | sed 's:.*/n.*e\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.grd:\1:' | sort -u)
known_lats=$(find . -type d -print | grep -oP 'lat\K\d+(?=/?)' | sort -u)

print_matrix() {
    echo -ne "\t"
    paste -s - <<<"$known_longs"
    for lat in $known_lats
    do
        echo -en "$lat:"
        for long in $known_longs
        do
            [[ -e "./lat${lat}/n${lat}e${long}.grd" ]] && echo -en "\t+" || echo -en "\tno"
        done
        echo
    done
}
print_matrix
```

The logic is easy:

- search for all *known* longs e.g. for the filenames what contains `eNNN`
- search for all *known* lats e.g. for the directories wit `latNN`
- in a cycle test the existence if the files

The above printed matrix is probably not very useful, because you probably want do something with the found or missing files, so here is an *action* variant of the script.

```
start="./test/grid"
cd "$start" || err "can cd to $start" || exit 1

known_longs=$(find . -type f -name \*.grd -print | sed 's:.*/n.*e\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.grd:\1:' | sort -u)
known_lats=$(find . -type d -print | grep -oP 'lat\K\d+(?=/?)' | sort -u)

do_if_exists() {
    local xlat="$1"
    local xlong="$2"
    filename="n${xlat}e${xlong}.grd"
    #do nothing
}

do_if_missing() {
    local xlat="$1"
    local xlong="$2"
    filename="n${xlat}e${xlong}.grd"
    echo "from lat$xlat missing $filename"
}

do_actions() {
    for lat in $known_lats
    do
        for long in $known_longs
        do
            [[ -e "./lat${lat}/n${lat}e${long}.grd" ]] && do_if_exists $lat $long || do_if_missing $lat $long
        done
    done
}
do_actions
```

what for the missing file do an action (echoes what missing), and the output is the next:

```
from lat35 missing n35e114.grd
from lat35 missing n35e115.grd
from lat35 missing n35e116.grd
from lat35 missing n35e117.grd
from lat35 missing n35e118.grd
from lat35 missing n35e119.grd
from lat35 missing n35e120.grd
from lat36 missing n36e111.grd
from lat37 missing n37e111.grd
from lat37 missing n37e115.grd
from lat37 missing n37e117.grd
from lat37 missing n37e119.grd
from lat37 missing n37e120.grd
from lat38 missing n38e111.grd
from lat38 missing n38e120.grd
from lat39 missing n39e111.grd
from lat39 missing n39e114.grd
from lat39 missing n39e115.grd
from lat39 missing n39e116.grd
from lat39 missing n39e117.grd
from lat39 missing n39e118.grd
from lat39 missing n39e119.grd
from lat39 missing n39e120.grd
```

Of course, is possible optimise more, like:

- do the find only once (helps if the directory tree is large - by creating a list of filenames by the `find command`
- don't test each file, but test the existence of the filename in the previously created list of filenames

like in the next

```
startdir="./test/grid"
(cd "$startdir" || err "can cd to $start" || exit 1

gridlist="/tmp/griglist.$$"
trap "rm -f $gridlist;exit" 0 2

find . -regex '\./lat[0-9][0-9]*.*' -print >$gridlist
known_longs=($(sed -n 's:^.*/n[0-9][0-9]*e\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.grd$:\1:p' $gridlist | sort -u))
known_lats=($(grep -oP '/lat\K\d+((?=/?)|$)' $gridlist | sort -u))

full_list() {
    for lat in ${known_lats[@]}
    do
        for long in ${known_longs[@]}
        do
            echo "./lat${lat}/n${lat}e${long}.grd"
        done
    done
}
comm -13 $gridlist <(full_list)) | while read missing
do
    #do something with the miising file
    echo "$missing"
done
```